# sqlite3.IntegrityError: Datatype Missmatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

When I run my code, i am getting an error saying "sqlite3.IntegrityError: Datatype Mismatch". I believe it's something to do with database but I can't seem to find the error. I checked if i have let a foreign key of a particular datatype reference an attribute of a different datatype but still can't find the error. Here is my database:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblCustomer (
    customerID TEXT (6),
    firstName TEXT (10),
    secondName TEXT (15),
    dob DATE,
    address TEXT,
    telephone INT (11),
    primary key (customerID)
    )""")
tblCustomer = []

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblEmployee (
    employeeID TEXT (6),
    firstName TEXT (10),
    secondName TEXT (15),
    dob DATE,
    address TEXT,
    telephone INT (11),
    gender TEXT,
    role TEXT,
    salary INT,
    primary key (employeeID)
    )""")
tblEmployee = []

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblBooking (
    bookingID TEXT (6),
    checkInDate DATE,
    checkOutDate DATE,
    numberOfOccupants INT,
    customerID TEXT,
    roomID TEXT,
    primary key (bookingID),
    foreign key (customerID) REFERENCES tblCustomer(customerID),
    foreign key (roomID) REFERENCES tblRoomAllocation(roomID)
    )""")
tblBooking = []

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblRoomAllocation (
    roomID TEXT (6),
    roomType TEXT (20),
    DateAdded DATE,
    DateVacated DATE,
    housekeepingID TEXT,
    primary key (roomID),
    foreign key (housekeepingID) REFERENCES tblHousekeeping(housekeepingID)
    )""")
tblRoomAllocation = []

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblHousekeeping (
    housekeepingID TEXT (6),
    dob DATE,
    assignedTo TEXT (20),
    primary key (housekeepingID)
    )""")
tblHousekeeping = []

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblPayment (
    paymentID TEXT (6),
    dob DATE,
    amountPaid CURRENCY,
    customerID TEXT (6),
    primary key (paymentID),
    foreign key (customerID) REFERENCES tblCustomer(customerID)
    )""")
tblPayment = []

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblOrder(
    orderID TEXT (6),
    price CURRENCY,
    customerID TEXT (6),
    treatmentID TEXT (6),
    primary key (orderID),
    foreign key (customerID) REFERENCES tblCustomer(customerID),
    foreign key (treatmentID) REFERENCES tblTreatment(treatmentID)
    )""")
tblOrder = []

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblTreatment(
    treatmentID TEXT (6),
    treatmentType TEXT (20),
    extras TEXT(20),
    employeeID TEXT (6),
    primary key (treatmentID),
    foreign key (employeeID) REFERENCES tblEmployee(employeeID)
    )""")
tblTreatment = []


cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblUser (
    userID TEXT (6),
    firstName TEXT (10),
    secondName TEXT (15),
    username VARCHAR(20),
    password VARCHAR (20),
    primary key (userID)
    )""")

tblUser = []
```

Comment: SQLIte does not have data type `DATE`.

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. Do we really need all of those tables with all of those columns to reproduce this problem? Also, please include the exact error message. When I run this code it doesn't give the error you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support `DATE` data type.

See what is supported:
https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Try using an INTEGER (store unix timestamp), or a TEXT (for iso8601 date).

Comment: I changed to TEXT and it's still giving me the same error